# PHP / Google Drive API - Upload tar.gz

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a tar.gz file (300MB) to Google drive but for some reason this is not working.

Have already tried to change the mime-type but with no success.

What I am doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');

$data = file_get_contents('document.tar.gz');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    ));

print_r($createdFile);

?>
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: No. Just does not uploading. I mean, the file is not found in the drive.

Comment: Uploading a .tar.gz file with a mime type of 'text/plain' is clearly incorrect.  When you print_r($createdFile) what do you see? If it's a File resource with an ID, then your file has been successfully uploaded and your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: use try catch print the statement in catch. You should have an error.